# Get index/position of the tag using text in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

Here is html chunk:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><td>
  <td>
    <img src="../imgs.gif">
  <td>
  <td><td>
  <td><td>
  <td><td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to iterate over **< td >** attributes and and get the index position of **< img >** attribute. In this case, the output should be **"1"**.

Tried a lot of xpath strategies including index-of(), count(), etree etc.

As I suspect, the following should be close.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"E:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

td = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr//td")
target = td.find_element_by_xpath("*[. = '../imgs.gif']")
children = td.find_elements_by_xpath("*")
print children.index(target)
```

Comment: `index-of()` should work, but its 1-indexed, so you need to subtract 1 in your case. What where your results with index-of?

Comment: html = browser.page_source
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
tree.xpath("index-of(//tbody//tr//td, //img[.='../imgs.gif'])")

returns XPathEvalErorr: Unregistered function
I guess index-of() is compitable only with Xpath 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about identifying the image and counting the preceding td sibling and adding one to it.

```
$x("count(//img/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td) + 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried a bit different approach that works.

```
    html = browser.page_source
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    re = tree.xpath("//tbody//tr//td")
    for i in range(0, len(re)):
        res = re[i].xpath(".//img//@src")
        for img in res:
            print repr(img)
            print "img number in list:", i
```